# SQLite database as IntentService, caching database state?

Tags: android, intentservice

The documentation for Android's SQLite interfaces mention that database accesses should be performed from an `IntentService` as they are potentially long-running operations, so the GUI thread should not block on them.

The `IntentService` is shut down as soon as no further `Intent`s are queued for it, which would happen basically after every request, so the database handles are built up and destroyed for each query as well, which seems wasteful.

- Is there a way to keep an `IntentService` around longer, or somehow otherwise avoid a race between the GUI thread posting more `Intent`s and the service answering them?
- Should I just make my query `Intent`s contain a list of queries that should all be performed, or would that cause other problems with message sizes?

Comment: "The documentation for Android's SQLite interfaces mention that database accesses should be performed from an `IntentService`..." -- where are you seeing this? I went looking for it and I'm not finding it. That is a dated recommendation, since `IntentService` itself is more or less deprecated.

Comment: One such place is the Note in the ["Create a database using an SQL helper" chapter](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#DbHelper) of the SQLite introduction.

Comment: Thanks! I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124546335) to try to get that updated.

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation for Android's SQLite interfaces mention that database accesses should be performed from an IntentService as they are potentially long-running operations, so the GUI thread should not block on them.

I/O of all forms should be performed on background threads, so as not to block the main application thread. `IntentService` itself is not a great choice, given changes on Android 8.0+.

A more typical approach nowadays is to have database access be managed by a singleton repository (whether a manually-created singleton or a singleton supplied to you via a dependency injection framework). The repository can use any number of approaches to provide a reactive API while doing the I/O on a background thread, including:

- RxJava
- `LiveData` and ordinary threads, executors, etc.
- Kotlin coroutines

If you use Room as your database access layer, it gives you all three of those options "for free". Some other ORMs offer similar capabilities.

> Is there a way to keep an `IntentService` around longer, or somehow otherwise avoid a race between the GUI thread posting more Intents and the service answering them?

Background services can only run for one minute. If your concern is the overhead in opening the database, use a singleton repository, and only open it once per process invocation. It's also entirely possible that you do not need a service; if you have a foreground UI, a service may be pointless.

> Should I just make my query Intents contain a list of queries that should all be performed...?

Um, possibly, but again, using a service here may not be necessary and definitely makes the problem more complex.

So: use a background thread for I/O. That does not have to involve a service.

Comment: I target 7.0 (because that's what my phone uses), and I have both a home screen widget and foreground UI, so it kind of makes sense to have a service, I think.

Comment: @SimonRichter: "I target 7.0" -- if you mean `targetSdkVersion`, that has only a minor impact on the decision-making here. "I have both a home screen widget and foreground UI, so it kind of makes sense to have a service" -- there is no particular need for a service for either scenario, unless the app widget uses an `AdapterView` (in which case you need a `RemoteViewsService`). That doesn't change my recommendation to isolate your data access inside of a repository.